# Exception thrown at 0x69F1454A (nvoglv32.dll) in Playground.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0A08D000

Tags: c, opengl

I want to display a texture but the compiler (Visual Studio 2017) gives me this error:

`Exception thrown at 0x69F1454A (nvoglv32.dll) in Playground.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0A08D000.`

The loadBMP_custom function has been taken from this website: 
http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-5-a-textured-cube/

Any help is going to be appreciated.

This is my code:

```
#include <GL\freeglut.h>

#include <stdio.h>


GLuint loadBMP_custom(const char * imagepath) {

unsigned char header[54]; 

unsigned int width, height;
unsigned int imageSize; 

GLuint textureID;  

unsigned char * data;

FILE * file;

file = fopen(imagepath, "rb");

printf("%s\n", imagepath);


if (!file) { 
printf("Image could not be opened\n"); 
return 0; 
}


if (fread(header, 1, 54, file) != 54) { 
    printf("Not a correct BMP file\n");
}

if (header[0] != 'B' || header[1] != 'M') {
    printf("Not a correct BMP file\n");
}


imageSize = *(int*)&(header[0x22]);     //34
width = *(int*)&(header[0x12]);         //18
height = *(int*)&(header[0x16]);        //22


if (imageSize == 0)    imageSize = width*height * 3;




data = (unsigned char* )malloc(imageSize);


fread(data, 1, imageSize, file);

fclose(file);

for (int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i)
{
    int index = i * 3;
    unsigned char B, R;
    B = data[index];
    R = data[index + 2];

    data[index] = R;
    data[index + 2] = B;

}

glGenTextures(1, &textureID);


glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);


glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, 
GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);    

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

return textureID;
}


void displayMe(void) {

GLuint bmp;




glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);



glPushMatrix();

bmp = loadBMP_custom("C:\\Dev\\Playground\\Release\\template.bmp");

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, bmp);

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0); 

glTexCoord2f(0.1, 0.0);
glVertex2f(0.1, 0.0);                    

glTexCoord2f(0.1, 0.1);
glVertex2f(0.1, 0.1);                    

glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.1);
glVertex2f(0.0, 0.1);                    
glEnd();


glPopMatrix();

glutSwapBuffers();
}







void reshape(int w, int h) {
glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(60.0, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 1.0, 30.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -3.6);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(800, 800);                   

glutCreateWindow("hi");   

glutDisplayFunc(displayMe);

glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please take time to ident your code and use empty lines consistently.

Comment: Please format your example code. But before: Try to find a MINIMAL example which shows the error. We are not the "repair my application" team.

Comment: This is a runtime error, from when your program executes. Therefore, it has nothing to do with the compiler giving you anything.

Comment: Show more code, like the allocation of `data`.

Comment: Reloading the texture in each frame is a terrible idea. Do it once before the main loop. And you should find out in which line the exception occurs. Use a debugger and step through until it crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> if (imageSize == 0)    imageSize = width*height * 3;
> [...]
> data = (unsigned char* )malloc(imageSize);
> [...]
> glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
> ```

You are telling OpenGL that it should interpret the `data` pointer as describing an image with RGBA components at each pixel, each as bytes, but you provide only RGB data, which means that the GL will access beyond the end of your buffer.

The last three parameters of `glTexImage` describe the image data in *client memory*: the numer and order of the channels, the data format for each channel, and the pointer to the first pixel. The `GL_RGB` you use as `internalFormat` just describes the format the GL shall internally store the texture at.

The correct code should be

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1); // use tightly-packed data buffer with no padding between image rows
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```